# Loop through selected text on outlook and convert into Hyperlinks and Change (Text To Display)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, hyperlink

While I am still composing a new email message, I need the following:
1- Convert the selected text into a hyperlink(s).
2- Change (Text To Display) to a constant string "`Hyperlink`" + ascending number (1,2,...).

the composition of selected text begins with **http** and end with a **dot+file extension**

like these examples:
http://xxxxxxx.pdf     http://xxxxxxxxxxx.doc     http://xxxxxxxxxx.xls
the below works if the selection contains only one from the above example.

the problem I faced, Is How to loop through selection and convert each example into Hyperlink and Change (Text To Display)?

**Note**:
(1-) the eamil.body formated as a **Rich Text**.
(2-) when I copy the text from excel and paste into email.body , It is inserted automatically as a table.

```
Sub Hyperlink_and_TextToDisplay()
    
  Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim wDoc As Word.Document
  Dim rngSel As Word.Selection
    
  If Application.ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
     Set wDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
     Set olNameSpace = Application.Session
     Set rngSel = wDoc.Windows(1).Selection        'Current selection
     wDoc.Hyperlinks.Add rngSel.Range, Address:=rngSel, TextToDisplay:="Hyperlink"
  End If
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the text or graphic that you want turned into a hyperlink is selected?

Comment: You are copying the text from Excel then added to the email body as a Hyperlink?

Comment: @0m3r , paste in outlook as text.

Comment: What do you understand by **"selected text"**? **Where** do you make this selection? In an Excel range (looking to the used tags...) and you want inserting hyperlinks using addresses as each such cells content? Or, what? Where the above code should run? In Outlook, in Excel as automation?

Comment: Would it be feasible to use the Email Format HTML instead of Rich-Text? - Because with HTML this should be a fairly easy task. If Rich-Text is required I'm out of my depth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to use the code `inside Outlook`, try the following adapted code. In order to supply more required links, the code uses an array (`arr`). It may come from everywhere (automation from Excel, Word, text file etc.):

```
Sub Hyperlink_and_TextToDisplay()

   'it needs a reference to Word!
  Dim wDoc As Word.Document, rngSel As Word.Selection
  Dim El, i As Long, arr
  
  arr = Array("x.pdf", "y.doc", "y.xls") 'array to be used to supply the necessary hyperlink addresses
   
   For Each El In arr
        i = i + 1
        If Application.ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
           Set wDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor

           'You need to move selection (the blinking cursor) down, for the next hyperlink insertion:
           If Not rngSel Is Nothing Then rngSel.InsertParagraphAfter: rngSel.Move unit:=wdLine 'for HTML format!
           
           Set rngSel = wDoc.Windows(1).Selection 'the place where the cursor blinks inside the Outlook message window...
           
           wDoc.Hyperlinks.Add rngSel.Range, Address:=El, TextToDisplay:="Hyperlink " & i
        End If
    Next El
    
End Sub
```

If you intend to use it from Excel (as automation), try the next adapted version. It uses as 'source' a range selection:

```
Sub Hyperlink_and_TextToDisplay()
  'it needs references to Word and Outlook!
  Dim Outl As New Outlook.Application
  Dim wDoc As Word.Document, rngSel As Word.Selection
  Dim El, i As Long, arr
 
  arr = Selection.Value 'you need to select a range where you keep the hyperlink addresses
  
   For Each El In arr
        i = i + 1
        If Outl.ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
           Set wDoc = Outl.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
           
           'secont time insert a paragraph and move selection on it:
           If Not rngSel Is Nothing Then rngSel.InsertParagraphAfter: rngSel.Move Unit:=wdLine
           Set rngSel = wDoc.Windows(1).Selection 'this represents the place in the outlook message where the cursor blinks...
           
           wDoc.Hyperlinks.Add rngSel.Range, address:=El, TextToDisplay:="Hyperlink " & i
        End If
    Next El    
End Sub
```

No need to make the object variables `Nothing`. VBA takes care of clearing the garbage from memory immediately after the moment when such variables are out of scope...

My Outlook composes messages in **HTML format** and the above codes are tested in such an environment.

**Edited**:

I cannot reproduce your case (range containing URL text, being pasted as a table in Outlook), but try the next shorter code. If there is a selected table, it should work:

```
Sub TextToHyperlinkOutlook()
  Dim wDoc As Word.Document, rngSel As Word.Selection, cel As Cell, i As Long
  
  Set wDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
  Set rngSel = wDoc.Windows(1).Selection
  
   If rngSel.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        If rngSel.Range.Cells.count > 0 Then
             For Each cel In rngSel.Cells
                 If cel.Range.Text <> Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
                    i = i + 1
                     wDoc.Hyperlinks.Add cel.Range, Address:=Left(cel.Range.Text, Len(cel.Range.Text) - 1), TextToDisplay:="Hyperlink " & i
                End If
             Next
         End If
  Else
        If Asc(rngSel.Text) <> 13 Then
           wDoc.Hyperlinks.Add rngSel.Range, Address:=rngSel.Text, TextToDisplay:="Hyperlink from text 1"
        Else
            MsgBox "No any selection to be processed...", vbInformation, "Selection missing"
        End If
  End If
End Sub
```

It practically uses each table cell as the object to add the hyperlink...

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253913/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-loop-through-selected-text-on-outlook-and-conve); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I am still curious to know How URLs text can be spitted without using a delimiter!

Comment: @Soma You cannot! But you can use a trick if all involved strings to be split **starts with the same substring/prefix**.

Comment: Mr.FaneDuru , yes I mean to to be split **starts with the same substring/prefix**, if a available could you show me how it can be done?

Comment: @Soma It shouldn't be very complicated. I have a function solution in my mind. I do no think it can be written in a comment. To be understandable, I mean... But if you ask such a question and I will be available that time I will create that function and place an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the text or graphic that you want turned into a hyperlink first and then pass it as an anchor parameter. When it is done, you can use the following code, for example:

```
wordDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:="http:\\www.microsoft.com"
```

Comment: Yes I will make the text by manual selection, **But your answer is far away from what I need.**

Comment: Are you looking for a ready-made solution?