# Loop through rows of a table on outlook and change (Text To Display) to an ascending number per each row

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have used the below code to Loop through selection on outlook and convert into Hyperlinks and change Text To Display [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76260633/loop-through-selected-text-on-outlook-and-convert-into-hyperlinks-and-change-te).
it works but it adds the the ascending number incrementally to all cells like this picture:

[image]

My need is to add the ascending number per each row like this picture:

[image]

In advance, great thanks for all your help.

```
Sub Hyperlink_Outlook()

  Dim wDoc As Word.Document, rngSel As Word.Selection, cel As Cell, i As Long
  
  Set wDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
  Set rngSel = wDoc.Windows(1).Selection
    
  If Not rngSel Is Nothing And rngSel.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    If rngSel.Range.Cells.Count > 0 Then
       For Each cel In rngSel.Cells
         If Len(cel.Range.Text) > 10 Then
           i = i + 1
            wDoc.Hyperlinks.Add cel.Range, _
             Address:=Left(cel.Range.Text, Len(cel.Range.Text) - 1), _
             TextToDisplay:="Attachment " & i
         End If
       Next
    End If
  End If
  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looping through rows first (the following is **not** tested):

```
Sub Hyperlink_Outlook()

  Dim wDoc As Word.Document, rngSel As Word.Selection, cel As Cell, i As Long
  Dim r As Variant
  
  Set wDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
  Set rngSel = wDoc.Windows(1).Selection
    
  If Not rngSel Is Nothing And rngSel.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    If rngSel.Range.Cells.Count > 0 Then
      For Each r In rngSel.Rows
        i = 0 ' reset i here
        For Each cel In r.Cells
          If Len(cel.Range.Text) > 10 Then
            i = i + 1
             wDoc.Hyperlinks.Add cel.Range, _
              Address:=Left(cel.Range.Text, Len(cel.Range.Text) - 1), _
              TextToDisplay:="Attachment " & i
          End If
        Next cel
      Next r
    End If
  End If
  
End Sub
```

Comment: I got "Type mismatch error" at this line `For Each r In rngSel.Rows`

Comment: Ok, try `Dim r As Variant`

Comment: I tried `Dim r As Variant` and your code worked correctly .

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the next adapted code:

```
Sub Hyperlink_OutlookCols()
 'Columns in Excel must be autoFit
  Dim wDoc As Word.Document, rngSel As Word.Selection, cel As Word.Cell
  
  Set wDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
  Set rngSel = wDoc.Windows(1).Selection
    
  If Not rngSel Is Nothing And rngSel.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    If rngSel.Range.Cells.count > 0 Then
       For Each cel In rngSel.Cells
          If Len(cel.Range.Text) > 10 Then
             wDoc.Hyperlinks.Add cel.Range, _
              Address:=Left(cel.Range.Text, Len(cel.Range.Text) - 1), _
                                         TextToDisplay:="Attachment " & cel.Column.Index
          End If
       Next cel
    End If
  End If
  
End Sub
```

You should copy the cells from Excel after autoFit the respective columns...

Comment: You always have a new tricks, yes `.Column.Index` do the job perfectly, But I found that there no need to autoFit the respective columns in excel because after I paste on outlook it is autofitted automatically (in outlook).

Comment: @Soma This, probably, depends on your specific settings. In my case, **it does not** and  Word VBA does not behave as Excel  one. When try even invoking a specific column, it send an error message related to "not the same columns width", which is strange, but this is happening. In such cases, the empty cells are completely neglecting. I mean, using `Row(x).Cells.Count` returns only the number of non empty ones. I also tried `rngSel.Range.Tables(1).Columns.AutoFit` which works, but if the second column has an empty cell it executes `AutoFit`, but the third column is moved as the second...

Comment: Please, Dose the cell in a range on excel itself (and not an excel table) supports `.Column.Index` ?

Comment: @Soma Yes, in a way... I mean, you can test it, but without `Index`. `Debug.Print ActiveCell.Column` should return the column of the active cell. What do you try accomplishing, in fact?

Comment: As this question exactly but with a range in excel itself , I will prepare a question afternoon.

Comment: I have used `rng.column` but it dose not work, with using "Super Symmetry" approach (two looping) then it works.

Comment: @Soma This only proves that you used it wrongly... Anyhow, it could return correctly if you used it as it should, only due to the fact that the larger column (between the three involved) is larger.

Comment: I thought `rng.column` will give me the number of column in my range , but it gives me the number of column of the sheet itself, Please can you learn me the correct way?

Comment: @Soma Of course! `Column` refers the sheet. What do you mean by "the number of column in my range"? If you need `rng.columns(2).address` it will return the address of the range second column, supposing that the range in discussion has more than one column... Or `rng.columns(rng.columns.count).column` will return the number of the range last column, but referring the sheet, too.